# footer and header is not adding in android ListView - a bug fix

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a custom listView.
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewInit();

        adapter = new myPlanAdapter(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.violet_footer, null);

        listView.addFooterView(listFooterView);

        LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.blue_header, null);

        listView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/head"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="My Exam"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddMyPlanButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/myPlanListViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/trans_violet_half_round"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing ? The header and footer is not added.

Comment: Could you add header or footer layout definition? maybe the problem is the height of em...

Comment: @selvin footer layout also added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ashish : Please add some view in the LinearLayout and try, like I have changed the Your footer.xml file by adding one TextView . Replace the code and check the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/trans_violet_half_round"
android:orientation="vertical" > 

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. You solved my problem over three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/icicibg"
    >
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="My Exam"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddMyPlanButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add" />

  </RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"

    >

 <ListView
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/myPlanListViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>



<RelativeLayoutandroid:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/trans_violet_half_round"
    android:orientation="vertical"/ > 
</LinearLayout>
```